# Issues with iterating over groupby objects and merge left

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, iteration, pandas-groupby

I am using pandas to try and break a dataframe into different groupby object and then use those groupby objects to merge left onto another dataframe. The initial dataframe is:

```
Name    City     Date
Alice   Seattle  1/3/2019                
Mallory Portland 5/1/2020         
Mallory Seattle  6/2/2012 
John    Seattle  1/3/2019
Kim     Portland 5/1/2020
Kim     Portland 4/1/2018
```

Should be split into 4 new group by objects:

1:

```
  Name    City     Date
 Alice   Seattle  1/3/2019                
 John    Seattle  1/3/2019
```

2:

```
  Name    City     Date
Mallory Portland 5/1/2020         
Kim     Portland 5/1/2020
```

3:

```
  Name    City     Date
Mallory Seattle 6/2/2012
```

4:

```
  Name    City     Date
Kim     Portland   4/1/2018
```

I have used the groupby function which seems to work fine

`df3=df2.groupby(['City','Date'])`

The issue is occurring when I try and take these groupby objects and try and iterate over them. My goal is to create a table where I have a set order of names on the left and am using a merge left to get the city and dates to line up.

The order of names for example would be

```
Kim 
Mallory
John
Alice
```

and the final product should look like this

```
Name     City     Date     City     Date      City   Date  City     Date
Kim                        Portland 5/1/2020               Portland 4/1/2018
Mallory                    Portland 5/1/2020  Seatle 6/2/2012
John     Seattle  1/3/2019
Alice    Seattle  1/3/2019
```

Any help is appreciated here. Thank you.

Comment: A `groupby` doesn't return a dataframe, it returns a groupby object. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Edit your question with a mockup of the data you want to produce. Include how it's different from what you're starting with.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I cleaned up the question and hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: ^This isn't helpful

Comment: I guess the question could be set up such that we have the initial table and the final output with no details in between, but providing some structure to my line of thought seems better than none.